# Why is cypress timing out when evaluating this regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, testing, cypress

I'm new to cypress and am curious what I'm doing wrong.

I have a test which validates the contents of a table on a page.  One of those columns contains a formatted date--the date can be off by a little bit, so I'm using a regex to validate it rather than a strict comparison.

The test looks something like this:

```
it.only('I can see the date',  ()=> {

    // Match dates like 'Dec. 21, 2018 at 1:12 pm'
    const approximateTime = new RegExp(Cypress.moment().format('MMM[\]. D, YYYY [at] h:[.. [a|p]m]'));

    cy.get('table.activity-log').within(() => {
        cy.get('tbody tr').eq(0).within(() => {
            cy.get('td').eq(0).invoke('text').should('match', approximateTime);
...
```

I'm running it against HTML and it matches the expected element, which looks something like:

```
<td>
    Dec. 21, 2018
    <span> at </span>
    1:12 pm
</td>
```

The test runs and times out while retrying:

```
AssertionError: expected 'Dec. 21, 2018 at 1:12 pm' to match /Dec. 21, 2018 at 1:.. {a|p}m/
```

Am I doing something wrong with the `.invoke('text')`, or elsewhere in the test?

Comment: Try `'MMM[\]. D, YYYY [at] h:[.. (a|p)m]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out--there are two problems in the sample.

@ug_ spotted one issue, `moment.format()` doesn't do well rendering literal square braces.  Their suggestion to use a capture group solved that issue:

Before:
`moment().format('MMM[\]. D, YYYY [at] h:[.. [a|p]m]')`

After:
`moment().format('MMM[\]. D, YYYY [at] h:[.. (a|p)m]')`

In addition I realized the string being matched contains two `&nbsp;` characters which weren't being matched by a space in the regex.  Using a `\s` resolved that.

The final pattern is now:
`moment().format('MMM[\\.] D, YYYY[\\sat\\s]h:[\\d{2} (a|p)m]')`

Once I fixed the pattern the test passed as-expected.